# Flutter CameraController initialize issue issue in android version 13

Tags: android, flutter, camera, android-camera

Getting camera initialize issue in flutter with android 13. Following code used for camera initialize:

CameraController? controller;

controller = CameraController(
cameraDescription,
ResolutionPreset.veryHigh,
imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.jpeg,
enableAudio: true,
);

Following library used for camera:
camera 0.10.5

Update android targetVersion 33